# Understanding TE and TM modes in plane harmonic waves

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves

I've been researching the concept of Transverse Electric and Magnetic modes, and I've found in this Wikipedia article that TE, for example, is defined when there is just $H$ in the direction of propagation, and no $E$ at all. Nonetheless, my professor keeps referring to TE and TM modes in plane harmonic waves, and it's a well known result that $\vec{E}\perp \vec{k}\perp\vec{H}$ in this kind of waves. Therefore, how can a plane harmonic wave present TE and TM modes, if neither $E$ nor $H$ can go along the direction of propagation?

Comment: see https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_24.html#Ch24-F17

Answer (score 1):

In TE, there is an $H_z$, and in TM is an $E_z$.

The TM mode equations are
\begin{eqnarray}
E_z(x,y)&=& E_0\sin(l\pi x/A)\sin(m\pi y/B)\\
E_x(x,y) & = & \frac{ikl\pi}{A\gamma^2}E_0\cos(l\pi x/A)\sin(m\pi y/B)\\
E_y(x,y) & = & \frac{ikm\pi}{B\gamma^2}E_0\sin(l\pi x/A)\cos(m\pi y/B)\\ 
H_x(x,y) & = & \frac{-i\epsilon\omega m\pi}{cB\gamma^2}E_0
\sin(l\pi x/A)\cos(m\pi y/B)\\ 
H_y(x,y) & = & \frac{i\epsilon\omega l\pi}{cA\gamma^2}E_0
\cos(l\pi x/A)\sin(m\pi y/B).
\end{eqnarray}
$E_0$ is the maximum magnitude of $E_z$ in the wave guide.  Each of the five vector components given above should be multiplied by
$e^{i(kz-\omega t)}$ to get the full $x,y,z,t$ dependence of the wave.

The TE modes are
\begin{eqnarray}
H_z(x,y)&=& H_0\cos(l\pi x/A)\cos(m\pi y/B)\\
H_x(x,y) & = & \frac{-ikl\pi}{A\gamma^2}H_0\sin(l\pi x/A)\cos(m\pi y/B)\\
H_y(x,y) & = & \frac{-ikm\pi}{B\gamma^2}H_0\cos(l\pi x/A)\sin(m\pi y/B)\\ 
E_x(x,y) & = & \frac{i\mu\omega m\pi}{cB\gamma^2}H_0
\cos(l\pi x/A)\sin(m\pi y/B)\\ 
E_y(x,y) & = & \frac{i\mu\omega l\pi}{cA\gamma^2}H_0
\sin(l\pi x/A)\cos(m\pi y/B).
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: So I understand a plane harmonic wave would have neither TE nor TM, since there is no field at all in the direction of propagation? I know this is called TEM mode, but my professor refers to plane waves as TE and TM

Comment: Don't you see H_z for TE and E_z for TM?

Comment: Oh right excuse me!